# Managing web.config for teams in VS2010 & TFS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, web-config

With VS2010's mandate that web.config be included in the project, how do we allow everyone to keep their own custom config file without getting into source control problems?

Previously, we would simply leave web.config out of our project, allowing everyone to keep their own local version of web.config on their machine. We moved to VS2010, and it is now forcing me to add web.config to my project in order to run debug mode. Because our project is linked to TFS, it automatically adds web.config to source control and tries to maintain it that way.

Is there a way to run in debug mode without including web.config in your project? Or is there a better way to manage config files?

Comment: Just curious, what information in the web.config is different between developers?

Comment: @itchi: Could be many things from DB connections to any web service bindings, app settings, authorization etc... Can be so many things that I can't even imagine.

Comment: Here's a quick fix (one step in VS) but it does put the responsibility on the developer to "monitor" changes. The file is left in the project as you required. Basically you tell TFS not to get / check out / check in this particular file by using "Cloak": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741975/how-can-i-always-block-checkin-of-a-specific-file-in-tfs

Answer (score 32):

I hope this helps someone.  I've used this methodology for the past couple of months now.  This is really easy to do.  I am using VS 2010 with TFS 2010.  Let's break it down:

- All web config files are now "DependentOn" the "web.config"
- Each developer or team needs their own "[User/Team].Debug.config"
- Config files should be transformed regardless if we're "Publishing" in release mode or not.

Here's how it's done:

1. Right-click the Web project you want to do this to and choose "Unload Project" (not "Remove Project").
2. Right-click the same Web project again (should be grayed-out now) and choose "Edit ...csproj".  This will open the project in an Xml editor.
3. Scroll down until you find the section that has all the "Web.config" listings.  Now, comment out all the "DependentUpon" elements in the Xml.
4. Close the Xml editor and save your changes.  Next, right-click on your project again and choose "Reload".  When the project reloads, you will notice that the Web.configs no longer "stack" under the "Web.config".  This is necessary in order to "trick" TFS.
5. Now, copy the "Web.config" file, paste it in the same project and rename it to "Web.base.config".  This is going to be used to re-generate the Web.config each time (covered next).
6. Now, select the Web.config file and go to "File --> Source Control --> Exclude Web.config from Source Control".  Also, Open the Source Control Explorer (TFS Explorer view) and find the location of where your Web.config is and delete it from TFS.  This is done because the Web.config will get re-generated each time you build the project (which I will cover next).
7. Now, we're going to create a new Build file that will help us regenerate the Web.config for any Built Type, even Debug ones (which is what the Web.config Transformed lacked to begin with).  Create a new Xml file in your project and rename it to "[YourProjectName].wpp.targets".  It is important to name this exactly what your project is called including all dots, dashes, etc (ex. My.Project.wpp.targets).
8. Now, enter the following Xml into the new file.  Do not worry if it starts underlining syntax errors:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
       <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
                  AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

       <!-- Make sure web.config will be there even for package/publish -->
       <Target Name="CopyWebConfig" BeforeTargets="Build;Rebuild">
           <Copy SourceFiles="Web.base.config"
                 DestinationFiles="Web.config"
                 OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
                 SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
       </Target>

       <Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
           <Message Text="Transforming: Web.$(Configuration).config" Importance="high" />
           <TransformXml Source="Web.base.config"
                         Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config"
                         Destination="Web.config" />
       </Target>
   </Project>
   ```
9. Now, from this point on, you NEVER, NEVER edit the Web.config, it will be overwritten every time the app compiles.  You only edit the "Web.base.config".
10. Now, let's make the Project look like it was.  Right-click the Project again and "Unload" it.  Now, right-click again and "Edit" it.  Now, go back and un-comment all the Elements we commented out in Step #3.  Also, you should add the "DependentOn" element under the "Web.base.config" element so that it will show up under the "Web.config" as well.  Close and save it, then reload your project again.  You should notice that all the configs are now under the "Web.config" again.
11. At this point, you can add as many Configurations to your Project / Solution as you want.  For example, I've added a Build Config called "Tim (Debug)", but the Project config is called "Tim.Debug".  When I right click the "Web.config" and choose "Add Config Transforms", it now adds my "Web.Tim.Debug.config" file.  You could also add configs per environment or per team.

---

It's worth noting that your individual config files are only a sub-set of the "Web.base.config" and they will be "Transformed" during any build process.  To switch which Transform is going to be built during debugging, just go to the top of your solution and choose which Build Config you want.  As long as you have a web.config for that Build Config, it will transform.  If not, you'll get the "Web.base.config" instead.

NOTE:  This should also work with standard Windows/WPF apps as well using the "app.config" instead.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. I made one change so that it wouldn't error if there wasn't a Web.Configuration.config: `<Target Name="ConfigurationTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')">`. And we should note that each developer has to be building in their own "Configuration". I wish there was a reliable way to include a "machine.config" in the project without VS constantly trying to check it in.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the way I was thinking of doing myself. So I searched and got it here. Great work Tim.

Comment: **One more Q**: since you've played with these MS build targets you likely know what to add to transform some other config files as well? Web config allows to have appSettings defined in a different config file i.e. *appSettings.config*. How do we add that one into transformations as well (dependant upon should be edited manually for those transforms to display hierarchically, but that's not a problem).

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Anyone know if this will work with **TFS Build**? I want something like Web.Staging.config so that it will auto build and publish to development/staging environment.

Comment: I think 7th step need to correct: "before delete web.config from TFS need to close solution otherwise web.config will be deleted from web-project too".

Comment: I used your basically your script, but changed it a little bit because of some (unknown) reasons, BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild didn't execute the task. I wrote everything inside the predefined BeforeBuild target. (I am using visual studio 2012)

Comment: What causes the wpp.targets file to get executed? Don't we have to add something into the project file?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen a good answer for managing different web.config files per developer with TFS to date.

However if the issues that cause developers to require different web.config files are addressed instead, this typically results in better results regardless of the chosen version control system.

For example, less differences between developer environments will reduce Works On My Machine (WOMM) arguments and will often also reduce the configuration changes for environments beyond development (eg Test, Production) which in turn simplifies deployment and reduces annoying environment-configuration-specific bugs.

Depending on the nature of the configuration item, there are usually several different strategies to mitigate per-environment differences. Many of which I suspect already have answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Jarrett,

All I have is an anecdote about how we handle the situation.

We have a team of 4 programmers.

We use a source control solution outside of VS -- TortoiseSVN. We each maintain our own local web.config which is included in the project. The project file is included in the repository, but we have the web.config set to "Ignore on commit" status.

I'm not sure what source code control you are using, but subversion with Tortoise SVN (which runs outside of Visual Studio) has worked great for our small team. Most of us program on two separate machines... one at the office, one at home.. so when you couple that with the fact that we have two production servers, we're comfortably dealing with 10 web.config's per project.

With that said, you have to remember to bring over another developer's web.config file when you setup a new development computer, otherwise the solution will either not load properly, or setup a default web.config which does not contain the appropriate connection strings and app settings.

And a final note: We're using IIS 7 for debugging

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using TFS2010 here, so it doesn't have the same flexibility of SVN. I wish it had the simple ability to ignore a single file.

Comment: Jarret, I thought my advice might not be completely relevant, just thought I'd share my experience

Answer (score 1):

SO has a good answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431565/it-is-possible-to-have-different-web-config-files-for-a-team-foundation-server-pr) ..  I havent checked out the multiple web.configs in VS2010 but I wonder if this was added because of the changes they did make to web.conig..

Comment: Yup, I looked into that, and that will work when moving to a different server. But, I don't want to check every dev's version of web.config in (as well as having to create a different build profile) so I was hoping to just avoid the checkin altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I have used T4 templates to solve this. Instead of having a web.config, you have a web.tt which generates a web.config. In the web.tt file you can generate different code based on the machinename or the current user.

Comment: I'd love if you can point to some resources on doing this, I've heard a lot but never played with T4 Templates

Comment: ha ok, fair enough. I'll see your link and up you some automation ; ) http://letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=t4%20template