# Working with Web.Release.config (Web.config transformation)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, transform, configuration-files, transformation

In my Web.config file have the following setup:

```
<add key="ClientMail" value="ridermansb@bindsolution.com"/>
```

In my file I Web.Release.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientMail"
                xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
                xdt:Locator="Match(value)"
                value="ridermansb@gmail.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

How do I get when running the site in Release mode, the settings are being applied in Web.Release.config?

In this case I need to change the value of a setting in `<appSettings>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this only applies when publishing a release. Otherwise you need to include a build event to cause a merge in a config build for a named build config. If you are interested in that let me know and I'll find my post on here regarding that.

Learn about web config transformations here: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/16/visual-studio-2010-web-config-transforms.aspx

Comment: It would be interesting, and yes I am interested, thanks for the help. I'll also look to your blog.

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590157/how-to-merge-all-web-configs-at-once-for-a-mvc3-app