# Web.config and different configurations in different projects missmatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, slowcheetah

I'm using this code (in my DAL project):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]`

to access appsettings section in web.config file (from web project):

```
<appSettings>
<add key="server" value="server.name.com"/>
<add key="database" value="databasename"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in a Web.Debug.config I'm using a following transformation

```
<add key="server" value="MY-LAPTOP"
     xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

after that when I start application the config file isn't transformed. First line of code returns the nontransformed infromation. What's wrong with the code? What am  i missing?

I have tried to publish it and when I check config file everything is ok like it is ment to be.

Comment: do you get a runtime error?  How do you know it wasn't transformed?  What evidence lead you to that?  Can you give us more info about how you are doing the transformation?

Comment: For transformation I used that code (3rd) in web.debug.config and I have tested it looking what ConfigurationManager returns (1st code). In all configuration settings it returns "server.name.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config transformation is only perform during the publish process. You can still enable it on every build, when you it F5, see

- [ASP.NET Web Projects: web.debug.config & web.release.config](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx)
- [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)
- [Making Visual Studio 2010 Web.config Transformations Apply on Every Build](http://kfigy.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-visual-studio-2010-webconfig.html)

It's an MSBuild task to add.

Comment: Interesting! So how can I ensure that different developers can put their own settings in a way that not messes up with source control?

Comment: @Ante B. You could, see [Visual studio 2010 - Per Developer/machine/environment Web.Config settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953666/visual-studio-2010-per-developer-machine-environment-web-config-settings),