# Hide pending changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

There are some files in my team's solution that almost never need to be checked in. Each one of us has a slightly different version of these files (ex: configuration files pointing to our individual development database or slightly modified app.config). Therefore, these files are permanently present in the pending changes view.

Is it possible to hide these pending changes so we never check them in by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [How can I always block checkin of a specific file in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9741975/147211) are some options named. To not see your changes, you should follow the workspace approach.

Comment: Cloakin a file is interesting, but if the config file gets updated (exceptional change in the cache config for example), will the file be updated when retrieving the latest version?

Comment: No, the cloaking means it will be excluded from all actions regarding TFS, because it is not part of the workspace. In this case you have 2 options: first is to remove the cloaking for a moment, the second would be to open the file from server and copy/merge it manually to yours (using the compare tool, you can check what changed to the previous version)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you