# TFS is not recognizing a manually downloaded file in the project when I try to get it

Tags: tfs

Here is the use-case. There is a very large file in the TFS branch, let's say it is 50GB. When I try to get this specific file with a command line similar to this:

```
tf get $/Branch/very-large-file.dat
```

The operation fails because the required time for the download is larger than the time a VPN would stay connected and of-course TFS is behind a VPN. This is why I have download the file manually using a different approach. Problem is that once the file is in place in my local directory and I check which files need to be updated with the following command:

```
tf get $/Branch/ /recursive /preview
```

I see that the `very-large-file.dat` will be downloaded from TFS. And if I go again with:

```
tf get $/Branch/very-large-file.dat
```

This will just create the partial file in the directory and start downloading the file from scratch.

Is there a way to update the local version table on the server, so that TFS knows that I have the file locally without having to download it?

Comment: Great question, and welcome to StackOverflow!  I tried to clean up the formatting a little bit, removed the tags that tie this question to a version.  Please feel free to edit my edits if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS 2012 lcoal workspaces were added, in which case TFS will recognize the file and will compare it to the server version. In 2010 and earlier, the server will keep a list of files on your workspace stored on the server at all times, which will say that you didn't download the file. The server workspace is also cached on your client. I don't know of a way to tell TFS from the commandline or another simple way the file is up to date.

As [a workaround you could 'cloak' the large file to tell TFS you don't want to download it at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742947/736079).

Comment: I think that local workspaces also require you to have done a get in order for there to be an entry in the local workspace table for this file, otherwise it will be pended as an add, since you never downloaded it.

Comment: @Edward, I'm not entirely sure either. The Cloaking should work though... Though I don't find it the most elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, cloaking worked. Also agree that it is not the most elegant solution but it unblocks you to work undisturbed with the branch.