# Exclude csproj.user file from Visual Studio TFS Check in

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfvc, csproj-user

I am working on a solution where we're checking in code. Each time there is a check in, it checks in a csproj.user which reflects current user's config. How can we make a rule to not check in this file? We're using Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) with TFVC as our source control.

Answer (score 3):

You can include *.user in .tfignore file (.gitignore for Git), then delete these files from version control server and check in changes if .user file has already been added to version control server.

Create .ignored file if you are using TFVC, you can refer to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) article. (For Git, there is .gitignore file)

On the other hand, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741975/how-can-i-always-block-checkin-of-a-specific-file-in-tfs) is an similar issue.

Comment: I am not using git, I am using team foundation services. TFS

Comment: @Jacky For VSTS (Team Foundation services) with Team Foundation Version Control system (TFVC) , you can use .tfignore. By the way, there are TFVC and Git version control system in VSTS/TFS, there isn't TFS version control system. I think you mean TFVC.

Comment: Hi @starain, yes I mean TFVC, can you send me a link for the details using TFVC?

Comment: @Jacky You can refer to this article to create .ignored file. (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control). You can open file system, then create a txt file in current working folder (workspace mapping folder), then in the Pending Changes page, in the Excluded Changes section, choose the Detected changes link, select a file, open its context menu, and choose Ignore this local item, Ignore by extension, Ignore by file name, or Ignore by folder. After that it will create a .tfignore file.

Comment: Will this change need to take place for each user, or it will make the change for all users?

Comment: @Jacky You can add .tfignore file to version control, then others could get this file from server, after that the *.user files will be ignored too in others workspace.