# How to manage a per user Web.config with tfs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, tfs, web-config

I have a wcf service managed with tfs in order to enable multiple computers to use it.

The Web.config contains things like addresses and certificates which are different for each computer.

Every time someone does 'get latest version' he need to edit the Web.config and change back the certificate and address to match his computer.

I wanted to know if there is a better way to handle it.

I want the Web.config to be changed when getting latest version, but not the variables inside it that need to remain different, such as certificate names.

And one more thing, I don't have Internet on those computers, can't download packages on them.

Comment: [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953666/visual-studio-2010-per-developer-machine-environment-web-config-settings, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932059/managing-web-config-for-teams-in-vs2010-tfs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707749/developer-specific-app-config-web-config-files-in-visual-studio, try searching.

Comment: thanks - the web.config transformation was very helpful